# How to efficiently crawl a website using Scrapy

Tags: html, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to attempt web-scraping a real estate website using Scrapy and PyCharm, and failing miserably.

Desired Results:

- Scrape 1 base URL (https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/), but 5 different internal URLs ([https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/{**i**}-r/](https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/%7B**i**%7D-r/)), where {i} = 1,2,3,4,5
- Crawl all pages in each internal URL or using the base URL
- Get all href links and crawl all href link and get span tag data from inside each href link.
- Scrape around 5,000-7,000 unique listings as efficiently and fast as possible.
- Output data into a CSV file while keeping Cyrillic characters.

*Note: I have attempted web-scraping using BeautifulSoup but it took me around 1-2 min per listing, and around 2-3 hours to scrape all listings using a for loop. I was referred to Scrapy being faster option by a community member. I'm unsure if its cause of the data pipelines or if I can do multi-threading.*

All and any help is greatly appreciated.^^

**Website sample HTML snippet:** This is a picture of the HTML I am trying to scrape.

[image: snippet]

**Current Scrapy Code:** This is what I have so far. When I use the scrapy crawl unegui_apts I cannot seem to get the results I want. I'm so lost.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Import library
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request


# Create Spider class
class UneguiApartments(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'unegui_apts'
    allowed_domains = ['www.unegui.mn']
    custom_settings = {'FEEDS': {'results1.csv': {'format': 'csv'}}}
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/1-r/,'
        'https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/2-r/'
        ]
    headers = {
        'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.debug('callback "parse": got response %r' % response)
        cards = response.xpath('//div[@class="list-announcement-block"]')
        for card in cards:
            name = card.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()
            price = card.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract_first()
            city = card.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="areaServed"]/text()').extract_first()
            date = card.xpath('.//*[@class="announcement-block__date"]/text()').extract_first().strip().split(', ')[0]

            request = Request(link, callback=self.parse_details, meta={'name': name,
                                                                       'price': price,
                                                                       'city': city,
                                                                       'date': date})
            yield request

        next_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="pager-next"]/a/@href').get()
        if next_url:
            # go to next page until no more pages
            yield response.follow(next_url, callback=self.parse)

    # main driver
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(UneguiApartments)
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a number of issues:

1. The `start_urls` list contains invalid links
2. You defined your `user_agent` string in the `headers` dictionary but you are not using it when yielding `request`s
3. Your xpath selectors are incorrect
4. The `next_url` is incorrect hence does not yield new requests to the next pages

I have updated your code to fix the issues above as follows:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

# Create Spider class
class UneguiApartments(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'unegui_apts'
    allowed_domains = ['www.unegui.mn']
    custom_settings = {'FEEDS': {'results1.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},
                       'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"}
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        cards = response.xpath(
            '//li[contains(@class,"announcement-container")]')
        for card in cards:
            name = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='name']/@content").extract_first()
            price = card.xpath(".//*[@itemprop='price']/@content").extract_first()
            date = card.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__date')]/text())").extract_first()
            city = card.xpath(".//*[@itemprop='areaServed']/@content").extract_first()

            yield {'name': name,
                   'price': price,
                   'city': city,
                   'date': date}

        next_url = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'red')]/parent::li/following-sibling::li/a/@href").extract_first()
        if next_url:
            # go to next page until no more pages
            yield response.follow(next_url, callback=self.parse)


    # main driver
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(UneguiApartments)
    process.start()
```

You run the above spider by executing the command `python <filename.py>` since you are running a standalone script and not a full blown project.

Sample csv results are as shown in the image below. You will need to clean up the data using `pipelines` and the scrapy `item` class. See the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) for more details.

[image: Sample csv of crawled results]

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much. I had a question if you don't mind. How would I scrape the href urls to each listing and scrape inside each of them? Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: scrape span list content values inside each of them*

Comment: You have to extract the link url within each card. You can use `link = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='name']/@href").extract_first()`. You can then yield a request to that link using `yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_item)`. Of course you have to implement the callback function `parse_item` which will be called with the response of the request.